# Passing Object value to UIView

Tags: objective-c, iphone

See the code here

```
@interface StaticView : UIView {
    Properties *prop;
}
@property (retain) Properties *prop;
@end
```

and i am attaching this view via code

```
[super viewDidLoad];
StaticView *sView = [[StaticView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
sView.prop.glowIntensity = 0.85f;

[self.view addSubview:sView];
```

but in my drawRect Method of StaticView i am always getting prop.glowIntensity = 0.0000

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
        NSLog(@"%f", prop.glowIntensity);
}
```

Here is my Properties.h

```
@interface Properties : NSObject {
    UIColor *bgColor;
    UIColor *foreColor;
    float glowIntensity;
}
@property(retain) UIColor *bgColor;
@property(retain) UIColor *foreColor;
@property float glowIntensity;

-(void) initbgColor:(UIColor *)bgC foreColor:(UIColor *)fC glowIntensity:(float) gI;
@end
```

here is implementation Properties.m

```
#import "Properties.h"

@implementation Properties

@synthesize bgColor;
@synthesize foreColor;
@synthesize glowIntensity;

-(void) initbgColor:(UIColor *)bgC foreColor:(UIColor *)fC glowIntensity:(float) gI
{
    self.bgColor = bgC;
    self.foreColor = fC;
    self.glowIntensity = gI;

}
@end
```

How can i pass right value to my StaticView class?

Comment: We need to have a look at your implementation of `Properties`, too. Maybe the `glowIntensity` ivar isn't declared properly?

Comment: Code for Properties.h and Properties.m added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks you do not create or set your view's prop variable before using it - by default it equals nil and calling `glowIntensity` on nil object just returns 0.

Answer (score 3):

Try changing your code to this:

```
@property (assign) float glowIntensity;        // We don't want to retain the float like done by default (at least I think it's default)

- (void)initWithBgColor:(UIColor *)bgC foreColor:(UIColor *)fC glowIntensity:(float)gI {
    if (self = [super init]) {        // We need to init self
        bgColor = bgC;                // Don't use the accessors in -init
        foreColor = fC;
        glowIntensity = gI;
    }
}
```

**Edit:** I think Vladimir is right, too.

Comment: assign is a default attribute for a property, so there's no need to set it (actually compiler won't let you create retain property for plain types). Good point about initWithBgColor method.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Vladimir! I just forgot about the error the compiler gives you.